# installing with pip returns error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users'

Tags: python, bash, pip, path, fedora

I have seen other threads that suggest using virtual environments, running as sudo, or installing for the specific user. None of these have solved my issue. I still get the same error.

Fedora36
Python 3.10

```
(base) pip install PySimpleGUI
Collecting PySimpleGUI
  Using cached PySimpleGUI-4.60.4-py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Installing collected packages: PySimpleGUI
Successfully installed PySimpleGUI-4.60.4
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 463, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 473, in _handle_target_dir
    ensure_dir(target_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 104, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users'
(base)
```

I have tried:

```
sudo pip install PySimpleGUI
Requirement already satisfied: PySimpleGUI in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.60.4)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

This works kind of but creates the obvious issue of installing as sudo. Also it seems very possible that I will create system issues.

```
(base) pip install --user PySimpleGUI
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'
(base) pip install PySimpleGUI --user
ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'
(base)
```

I believe that the issue is a path issue. Everything was kind of working but pip installed into my anaconda python bin instead of general bin. VSCode was not able to import the packages, even when selecting the anaconda python as my interpreter.

Currently, this is my which pip output.

```
(base) which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

I have tried figuring out whats going on in my .bashrc but I admittedly am not familiar with everything in there and do not want to screw anything up. I don't know if I am to meddle about within .bashrc or .bash_profile

I'd like to be able to use pip to install packages without sudo, user, or virtual env. It is like that on my windows partition and on my mac. I am not opposed to removing python and all associated packages.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.